# How to change color of specific part of string present inside special symbols, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

### Run code snippet so that you will be able to know what exactly I am trying to say.

I want specific portion of my string enclosed within special characters(say `[]` in my case), to change its color.

> I want to achieve this by retrieving string from `<input type="text" />`

I'm able to retrieve string ( present inside `[ ]` ) successfully but I'm not able to change color of that specific portion of string.
Below is what I've tried so far

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
        background:rgba(20,30,20,0.99);
        }
        div{
        color:orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:250px; overflow:auto;" id="inp" placeholder="for example type: this is [great] book john" />
    <p style="color:white;" id="dis"></p>
    <div></div>
    <script>
        $(function (){
        $("#inp").on("input" , function(){
        var inpt = $(this).val();
        $("#dis").html(inpt);
        var det1 = inpt.indexOf("[");
        var det2 = inpt.indexOf("]");
        var rpl = inpt.slice(det1 , parseInt(det2)+parseInt(1));
        var ptxt = $("#dis").text();
        if(det1 != -1 && det2 != -1){
        var lgnt = ptxt.length;
        var pslic = ptxt.slice(det1 , parseInt(det2)+parseInt(1));
        pslic.fontcolor("skyblue");
        ptxt.replace(ptxt.slice(0 , det1)+pslic+ptxt.slice(parseInt(det2)+parseInt(1) , lgnt));
        $("div").html(">>> "+pslic+"<<< <br> replacement executed successfully, check if color of "+pslic+" inside the white line is modified?");
        }
        });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
````

Comment: Is there no one in this entire world to answer my question .....

Comment: simply use `span` tag between your  `pslic` while printing and add css i.e: `span { color: skyblue; }` will give you required op .

Comment: If I am not wrong, what you are saying will only alter my string if `pslic` is predefined, but we are generating it from user's input so the string is variable in nature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `indexOf` of last char i.e : `]` from `pslic` and then we will use this to add `<span>` tag at the start of string after `[` and add closing `</span>` before end of `]` then apply required color to the text using css.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inp").on("input", function() {
    var inpt = $(this).val();
    $("#dis").html(inpt);
    var det1 = inpt.indexOf("[");
    var det2 = inpt.indexOf("]");
    var rpl = inpt.slice(det1, parseInt(det2) + parseInt(1));
    var ptxt = $("#dis").text();
    if (det1 != -1 && det2 != -1) {
      var lgnt = ptxt.length;
      var pslic = ptxt.slice(det1, parseInt(det2) + parseInt(1));
      //getting lst index of lst elemnt
      var end = pslic.indexOf("]");
      //leaving first char i.e : "[" ->add <span> "text" </span>-> "]" 
      var new_datas = pslic.substring(0, 1) + "<span>" + pslic.substring(1, end) + "</span>" + pslic.substring(end, pslic.length);

      ptxt.replace(ptxt.slice(0, det1) + pslic + ptxt.slice(parseInt(det2) + parseInt(1), lgnt));
      //adding new_dats to div
      $("div").html(">>> " + new_datas + "<<< <br> replacement executed successfully, check if color of " + new_datas + " inside the white line is modified?");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  color: skyblue;
}

body {
  background: rgba(20, 30, 20, 0.99);
}

div {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:250px; overflow:auto;" id="inp" placeholder="for example type: this is [great] book john" />
  <p style="color:white;" id="dis"></p>
  <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! One more question, what if I want to change color of string present inside `[ ]` not for once but for multiple times, say if we have [first] and [second] both as a substring in our input, only `[first]` will change its color to skyblue and the substring [second] will remain same...

Comment: Don't add `span` to other substring because in above code only text which is under `span` will get color .

Comment: Yes, but what I am asking is: can I loop if I have multiple substrings inside `[ ]` ? So that I can color of all such substrings?

Answer (score 0):

Use contains() Selector.

```
$(":contains('"+pslic+"')").css('color','skyblue');
```

Let me know if it's work. If you have similar texts on the same page, they all get affected.

Comment: `pslic` is `sliced` (point of slice is det1 and det2 variable and both the variables are predefined) string extracted from `p.text();` ...

Comment: Your code will change color of entire string, I want just my `pslic` to change its color ....

Comment: It's hard without a selector